# i can't get user location when i'm in the building with iOS 11

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager

i'm developing an iOS application using CLLocationManager to get current user location. 
When i'm out of the building it's work well but i'm come to in the building delgate of CLLocationManager always return 0 to me. 
Can i get exactly the location when i'm in the building?
I have checked on google maps and apple maps it's aways work well
Plz help me.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: hide this and try `[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];`
`

Comment: startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges -- it works only if location changes detected

Comment: When you are in the building, can you get your location in the Maps app?

Comment: Since you haven't mentioned that whether you are using apple or google map?  I would suggest to check your location in default  iOS Map and google map apps, if you can find the location in there with both of the map, then there is something is wrong with your code.

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan maybe my code is wrong something. I have checked on google map and apple map it's aways work well, but my app still return 0 with user location.

Comment: @wottle yes i can get my location with apple maps and google maps.

Comment: @ThanhBang, did you resolve your issue? If not. Are you getting any message in the debug console log?

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside a building then you are unlikely to be able to receive a GPS signal. Unless your building is a significant public place (airport, shopping mall) that has been added to Apple's indoor mapping then you will not get a location while indoors.

Comment: Thanks for information. But i don't know why in the same location but apple maps and google maps can get exactly location but my app can't. 
Maybe my source is wrong something else.

Comment: You should set your `distanceFilter` to `kCLDistanceFilterNone` and see if that helps.  The distance filter should be in meters, `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` is not a value you should use for this property